# Is there a way with promises to wait for user action

Tags: javascript, angular, es6-promise

I;m making a confirmation modal in Angular, this confirmation works like this:

**1.- I have a component (Alert.components.ts) which handles the template and has a subscription to Alert.service:**

```
export class AppAlertComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor(private alertService: AlertServiceDsm) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.alertService.onAlert()
      .subscribe(alert => {
        
        // this fires the confirmation modal
        this.initModal(alert);
      });
  }
```

In the template, I have an event binding when user clicks on yes

```
<button (click)="onConfirm()"> Yes </button>
```

**2.- I have a service (Alert.service.ts) which updates the subject when an alert is requested in any component:**

```
 fire(text: string) {

    this.subject.next(text);
  }
```

**3.- When any component needs to fire an alert it will call a method in Alert.service.ts which as I already told you, this updates the subject**

```
// in any other component    
this.alertService.fire('Are you sure?');
```

So I want to be able to do something like this:

```
 this.alertService.fire('Are you sure?')
      .then(response => {
        if (response) {
          // handle confirm logic here...
        } else {
          // close the alert
          this.alertService.remove();
        }
      })
```

But I'm stuck at how I'm able to triangulate a promise between service, alert.component and the component who fire the alert. If someone could help me I would be very grateful, and thanks in advance.

Comment: your `fire` method will need to return a Promise

Answer (score 0):

Did you try creating an extra variable, like a flag variable(a Subject maybe) and you push values to subject when the user does something and subscribe from another component that needs to listen to that action?